# Discovering Stack Overflow meta

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, new-users, help-center

***Learning The Ropes***

I've been using Stack Overflow for help on certain questions I had about programming for a little while now, as I have just started programming last month. As a newcomer, I was asking bad questions and have been limited to one question a week now. I don't want to lose my ability to ask questions so I looked for solutions and found Stack Overflow meta a few minutes ago. I don't quite understand what this is.

Is this a place for discussion or like a training place to train yourself to ask better questions?

I'm asking because I would like to ask minor questions that I couldn't find the answer to on here, but don't want to lose reputation points if they're asked incorrectly.

I've visited the FAQ and couldn't get a clear understanding about what this is. If I'm right about this being a place for beginners, I would love to contribute to this portion of the site until I'm ready for the main Stack Overflow.

***Question Summary:***

- Is this a discussion/forum area or a beginners version of Stack Overflow?
- Will reputation I earn and lose here affect my main Stack Overflow stats?
- Am I free to ask minor questions here without feeling repercussion from their quality?

Comment: Also see [the meta help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). And thanks for asking and trying to learn how it works instead of continually misusing the site. Kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a discussion place specifically for beginners -- rather meta is for all forms of discussion *about Stack Overflow* as opposed to *questions about programming*. The community discusses our standards here, interacts with moderators, proposes and discusses features, report bugs, etc.

If you have questions relating to how Stack Overflow is to be used, how to judge or improve the quality of your questions, etc, this is the place to ask them.  Voting here does not affect reputation in any way; votes generally express agreement or disagreement more than correctness or incorrectness.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'll be sure to get more involved in meta now.

Comment: @ArjunVaid Keep an eye out for the block on the regular Stack Overflow site labeled "Hot Meta Posts" in the right sidebar.   Meta posts currently getting a lot of community attention or generating interesting discussion will be featured there.

Comment: Oh okay cool I'll check it out! Can i earn reputation at all in meta?

Comment: No, not any longer. Until last year, the meta site for _all_ of the Stack Exchange network (http://meta.stackexchange.com/) was here at meta.SO and it earned reputation separately from SO. But that was spun off last year and SO given its own meta site without reputation, which is what all the other sites in the Stack Exchange network already individually had for their communities.